# Loading from .load_state_dict() when the save was done using torch.save('path')

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, onnx

So I have a pre-trained PyTorch model that was saved using

`torch.save(model,'path')`

but now I want to convert this into a TensorFlow model with onnx and in order to do this, I have to use

`pretrained_model.load_state_dict(torch.load('path'))`

However this is not possible directly since I did not save it with the state_dict in the first place, but unfortunately, I cannot retrain the model again and have to work with the saved file as it is.

Is there any way that I can recover the state_dict from the saved file?

I tried to use

`model1=torch.load('path')`

`torch.save(model1_state_dict(),'path1')`

and then load it again with state_dict(), but it gives me the following error:

> RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for Model:
> Missing key(s) in state_dict: "model1.0.weight", "model1.0.bias", "model1.2.weight", "model1.2.bias".
> Unexpected key(s) in state_dict: "0.weight", "0.bias", "2.weight", "2.bias".

Any help on adding these keys in state_dict manually to also recover the original model would be very helpful.

For the context, the trained model has dimensions [2,5,1], that is, the input dimension is 2, the output dimension is 1 and there's one hidden layer with 5 neurons.

Comment: `pretrained_model.load_state_dict(torch.load('path'), strict=False)` ; [refer here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html#torch.nn.Module.load_state_dict)
for more info. here the error most probably caused by layer name not being similar.

Comment: @Nipun Now I do not get that error anymore, but the weights and the biases of pretrained_model are different from model1, so I'm not sure if the problem is because strict=False?

Comment: how did you compare the model weight to say, weights are different?

Answer (score 0):

Old question but no satisfying answer.

The problem here is just that the parameter names are different in the `model` and the `state_dict`. (Because the model state_dict was saved instead of the model).

The solution would simply be to rename the `state_dict` keys:

```py
old_state_dict = torch.load('path1')
model1.load_state_dict({f"model1.{k}":v for k,v in old_state_dict.items()})
```